# Get Completed notification from each task running in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a list of `Task`. I want to run all tasks in parallel. I am doing it using following code.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    tasks.Add(file.DownloadAsync());
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

But on every task completion I need to update UI or need to do some other stuff. But in this case, it will wait for all tasks to be done. How can I achieve both parallel running of tasks and updating UI on every task done. Some task may take long time and some may not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest option is to have an `async` method that does that:

```
async Task DownloadAndUpdate(File file)
{
    await file.DownloadAsync();
    UpdateUI(file)
}
```

And await these tasks instead:

```
await Task.WhenAll(files.Select(file => DownloadAndUpdate(file)));
```

You can do that with a single lambda expression as well if a method is too much:

```
await Task.WhenAll(files.Select(async file => 
{
    await file.DownloadAsync();
    UpdateUI(file)
}));
```

Comment: It's in this case your actions will start only when all tasks will complete? I think op is asking about how to execute an action for each task immediately when the task completes.

Comment: @aush No. it doesn't wait for all tasks to complete.

Comment: you are right, I misread your answer. Still, I think the approach with continuations is better because you have more freedom when you combine your task instead of creating a "big" tasks. Same for god-method vs set of small methods with separated responsibilities.

Comment: @aush It's not. It's logically the same as `async-await` only much harder to get right. For example, unless you specify a `TaskScheduler` you can't update the UI.